# Is there a function in gmail filters to choose a forward and cc address?

Tags: gmail-api

My company just got a new expense reporting software that requires the user to forward an email receipt to an outside email address and the user must cc themselves onto that same email. I have been looking through the documentation and there doesn't seem to be a baked in way to select a forwarding address and add a cc address to the filter.

I have created a basic xml filter and have been looking at the gmail api, but there doesn't seem to be a command that does exactly what is required by the expense reporting software (webexpenses).

I can get my emails to forward, but without appending a cc recipient, the expense reporting software just rejects the email. Is there a property that I'm missing or a workaround to achieve the desired outcome?